# Save ringtones in wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8

Well I was wondering why i can't save ringtones on windows phone

```
SaveRingtone ringtone = new SaveRingtone();
ringtone.Source = new Uri("appdata:/"+path);
ringtone.DisplayName = b.Content.ToString();
ringtone.Completed += Ringtone_Save_completed;
ringtone.Show();
```

this is my code

Answer (score 0):

Well you was so close.

The class SaveRingtone it is SaveRingtoneTask

```
SaveRingtoneTask ringtone = new SaveRingtoneTask();
ringtone.Source = new Uri("appdata:/"+path);
ringtone.DisplayName = b.Content.ToString();
ringtone.Completed += Ringtone_Save_completed;
ringtone.Show();
```

and you will need to add

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;
```